# Google Play Store - is it mandatory to fix warnings in pre-launch report?

Tags: android

Does google reject the submitted application if warnings in pre-launch report are not fixed?

Comment: No, you can ignore those warnings.

Comment: Thanks Suraj. My Application is in "processing update" for 2 days. so i thought google is expecting me to fix the warnings and submit again...i can ignore those warnings and wait , right?

Comment: Yes you can ignore those and google is taking a week to review the application so wait for there response.

Comment: Thanks Suraj.I will wait for their response.